# How can we show the identity of the two following equations. Plane Earth Loss Model.

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to have a hint how to prove the following identity

$\frac{P_R}{P_T} = (\frac{\lambda}{4\pi *d})^2 * | 1 + R*e^{j*k \frac{2h_Th_R}{d}}|^2$

with R = -1 this should somehow results in

$\frac{P_R}{P_T} = 2 *  (\frac{\lambda}{4\pi d})^2 [1 - cos(k \frac{2h_Th_R}{d})]$

I thinks this is trivial but I am looking at this way to long now.

I just can not handle the absolute value squared in combination with the complex numbers inside. Where does the complex factor go.

References:
S. R. Saunders and A. Aragon Zavala, Antennas and Propagation for Wireless Communication Systems. 2007, p. 100. 
Plane Earth Loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this expression I think that the absolute value has a complex meaning (if that it's not clear 
[Read Absolute value in the complex numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Absolute_value_and_argument)
).
Let's suppose:
$$ b\ =\ (\frac{\lambda}{4\pi *d})^2 $$
$$ a\ = \ k \frac{2h_Th_R}{d} $$
Then we have to prove that:
$$b\ |1\ -\ e^{j*a}|^{2}\ =\ 2\ b\ |1\ -\ cos(a)|$$
First of all for the Eulero identity:
$$ e^{j*x}\ =\ cos(x)\ +\ j\ sin(x)$$
That imply:
$$b\ |1\ -\ e^{j*a}|^{2}\ =\ b\ |1\ -\ cos(a)\ -\ j\ sin(a)|^2\ =$$ 
But:
$$|x\ +\ j\ y|^2\ =\ x^2\ +\ y^2 $$ 
for each x + j y complex number,Then:
$$=\ b\ ((1\ -\ cos(a))^2\ +\ sin(a)^2)\ =$$
Then doing the product and using the identity:
$$ cos(x)^2\ +\ sin(x)^2\ =\ 1$$
We have:
$$ =\ b\ (2\ -\ 2\ cos(a))\ =\ 2\ b\ (1\ -\  cos(a))$$
That's what we want to prove.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved an engineer.

That simple equation did the trick:

$| x + jy |^2 = x^2 + y^2$

I added some reference for future search engine results.